# define only one line in header file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Suppose that there are three lines in a header file such as:

```
#define line1
#define line2
#define line3
```

I would like to be sure that line1 should be defined when all of the lines are commented. I also would like to know any two or three lines should not be active (not commented) at the same time. For example if line2 and line3 is active at the same time, compiler should generate an error.

How should i do that?

Comment: Use `#ifdef` and `#error` directives and combination of `&&` and `||` operators to generate the error  when required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `line1` is defined when nothing else is:

```
#if !defined(line1) && !defined(line2) && !defined(line3)
#define line1
#endif
```

Generate an error if more than one line is defined:

```
#if (defined(line1) && defined(line2)) || (defined(line1) && defined(line3)) || (defined(line2) && defined(line3))
#error "Your message here"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
#if defined(line2) && defined(line3)
    //generate error
#endif
```

Comment: "Maybe this helps you" is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this below the (possibly-commented) definitions of `line1`, `line2` and `line3`:

```
#define CHK(a,b,c) (defined(a) && !defined(b) && !defined(c))

#if !(CHK(line1,line2,line3) || CHK(line2,line3,line1) || CHK(line3,line1,line2))
    #error "Improper combination line1/line2/line3"
#endif
```

This should ensure that **exactly one out of three** definitions will be active.

Comment: In my opinion, this is more complex than it needs to be. For one, one might wonder whether it's intentional that the first `defined` inside `CHECK` is not negated.

Comment: @lethal-guitar: If I understand OP's intentions correctly, then he/she wants to be sure that **exactly one out of three** definitions is active.

Comment: Yes, and I don't doubt that your code achieves that. But in my eyes, a simpler and more verbose solution is easier to understand than having an additional macro one needs to read first.

Comment: @lethal-guitar: I see your answer above, and it seems to force the definition of `line1` when no other line is defined, instead of generating a compilation error. I'm not sure it answers OP's requirements in a precise manner.

Comment: yes, that's because he wrote: "I would like to be sure that line1 should be defined when all of the lines are commented"

Comment: @lethal-guitar: Thanks. I sort of inferred that what OP was really interested in, is a way to be sure that exactly one of the three is defined (without enforcing which one it would be).